# Cannon Sprites Lag Game Instead Of Rotating Towards Player

Tags: python, pygame

in my main loop, this is what I did V I told all my enemies to rotate towards the player but
it's lagging the game and the cannons aren't rotating to the player  [Lags Game + Sprites Not Rotating](https://gyazo.com/12816749754417abcabf48c408268fbb) -- as you can see they aren't rotating and for some reason, it's making my game lag to

```
# this goes inside the main loop and looks for
      
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y)) 

                 # even if I do lookAt((playerman.x,playerman.y)) instead of putt enemyshoot.lookAt they still don't rotate and my game still lags
```

my enemyshoot class

```
    #-------------------------------- enemy shoots left and right

    shotsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
    class enemyshoot:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.health = 10
            self.hitbox = (self.x + -20, self.y + 30, 31, 57)
           #-------------------------------------------------------
            # Make a Reference Copy of the bitmap for later rotation
            self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
            self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()-150,self.shootsright.get_height()-150))            
            self.image    = self.shootsright
            self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
            self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( ( x, y ) )
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            window.blit(self.shootsright,self.rect)
            self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100, 10)) # NEW
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 100, self.y + 160, 51, 65)
        def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            # Rotate image to point in the new direction
            delta_vector  = coordinate - self.position
            radius, angle = delta_vector.as_polar()
            self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( self.shootsright, -angle, 1 )
            # Re-set the bounding rectangle and position since 
            # the dimensions and centroid will have (probably) changed.
            current_pos      = self.rect.center
            self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = current_pos
            


            
    black = (0,0,0)
    enemyshooting = []
    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    platformList = []
    level = ["                                                                                                                        p               p         p                         p                        p        ",
             "                                       ",
             "                             ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                  ",
             "                           ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                    ",
             "                                   ",
             "                    ",]
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "p":
                new_platforms = enemyshoot(ix*10, iy*50, 10,10,(255,255,255))
                enemyshooting.append(new_platforms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CiroGarcía has provided assitance already. I am just going to add a suggestion. It seems like you are not scaling the canon images, just rotating them. If that is the case you can likely significantly improve your performance by prerotating the images that you are likely to need and then just selecting from those when you need to draw the canon.

From the video it looks like you do not need the full 360 degrees since the player is always below them, it would be at most 180 and looks like it would be only about a 120 degree or so range (from the angle of rotation required for the cannon on the far right to point to the player when on the far left side, to the angle of rotation require for the canon on the far left side to point to the player when on the far right). Also the number of images within that range can be reduced as well. You probably could not tell the difference if you only had an image for every 5 degrees and then selected the image rotated closest to the angle needed. A 120 degree range with one image every 5 degrees is 120/5, with 1 extra for the other end of the range. That is only 25 (= 120/5 + 1) images to keep around for fast display.

You figure out a which angles you need and pre-rotate those images and save them for later use.

Edit:

I also just noticed from your video that the canon images are not vertically aligned. They look like they are rotated slightly counterclockwise from the vertical (as a guess about 10-15 degrees or so). You would have to take that rotation into account and add or subtract it from the rotation amount when you are deciding how much to rotate them to make them point at the player.

Comment: how would I change the angle? to 120  I dont see where it says 360? [Video Of The Game Right Now](https://gyazo.com/d11cc0d0b6b424beee2bf1272e627aff)       my [enemyshoot class](https://pastebin.com/43FVWSHe) the image cannons kinda flipped

Comment: I am really confused on the rotating part  `self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( (200, (120/5 + 1)) )` this is what I have done but it still seems a little off [video](https://gyazo.com/3d035e5f632cc98a0b1412edb934afd6)

Comment: @HabibIsmail The 120/5 + 1 =  25 was supposed to be an estimation of how many images you would need to create. It assumed a 120 degree range with one image every 5 degrees is 120/5, with 1 extra for the other end of the range. The intent was you find the borders of the rotation that you need for your cannons (I guessed that range would be a 120 degree range by looking at you video) and then divide that up into 5 degree increments and rotate a canon image for each of those. The as I said above, just pick the rotation that is closest to pointing along you angle and use it.

Comment: @HabibIsmail The reason that your canons are not pointed in the direction you are shooting is likely that the image you are using does not point along the 0 degree angle. As I said in the answer above, you have to figure out how far off it is and compensate for that.

Answer (score 3):

You are saving the result of `pygame.transform.rotozoom( self.shootsright, -angle, 1 )` to `self.image`, while in the draw function you are displaying `self.shootsright`. You have to blit `self.image` instead. Also, if you are iterating through each enemy, and making them rotate every time the for loop targets them, instead of rotating them just once, the sprite will rotate infinitely at the max speed your CPU allows the script, and that is why it is lagging. You have to target only the enemies that are not looking at the player.

This is how I would do it:

enemyshoot class:

```
  #-------------------------------- enemy shoots left and right

    shotsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
    class enemyshoot:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.health = 10
            self.hitbox = (self.x + -20, self.y + 30, 31, 57)
           #-------------------------------------------------------
            # Make a Reference Copy of the bitmap for later rotation
            self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
            self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()-150,self.shootsright.get_height()-150))            
            self.image    = self.shootsright
            self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
            self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( ( x, y ) )
            self.isLookingAtPlayer = False
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
            self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100, 10)) # NEW
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 100, self.y + 160, 51, 65)
        def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            # Rotate image to point in the new direction
            delta_vector  = coordinate - self.position
            radius, angle = delta_vector.as_polar()
            self.image    = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, -angle)
            # Re-set the bounding rectangle and position since 
            # the dimensions and centroid will have (probably) changed.
            current_pos      = self.rect.center
            self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = current_pos
            


            
    black = (0,0,0)
    enemyshooting = []
    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    platformList = []
    level = ["                                                                                                                        p               p         p                         p                        p        ",
             "                                       ",
             "                             ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                  ",
             "                           ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                    ",
             "                                   ",
             "                    ",]
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "p":
                new_platforms = enemyshoot(ix*10, iy*50, 10,10,(255,255,255))
                enemyshooting.append(new_platforms)
```

for loop:

```
# this goes inside the main loop and looks for
      
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                if not enemyshoot.isLookingAtPlayer:
                    enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y))
```

I am not sure how would you detect if the sprite is looking at the player, but I guess it's just comparing the rotation vector of the enemy to the vector between the player and the enemy, and if they are not the same then call lookAt().

Comment: wait so      `self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( self.image, -angle, 1 )`
 also could you like help me with  how I could iterat through each enemy and make it rotate every time for the loop tragets him I an confused on that part I am still learning python as well

Comment: I would have a boolean for the enemies like `isLookingAtPlayer` or something like that, and it would be true if the enemy is looking at the player, and false if not. Then I would iterate through all enemies shooting that are not looking at the player, so when they do look at him, they are not targeted by the for loop. And as for the rotation, if you reasign the rotated image to itself, it will spin like a fan, you have to assign the rotated sprite to a different variable and then blit that new sprite.

Comment: You could have a `self.original_image` and a `self.image`. The `self.image` will be the modified version of the `self.original_image`. Then you would draw it by doing `window.blit(self.image, self.rect)`

Comment: the position of the cannas changed and here [video](https://gyazo.com/0dd4c1a6757963e0b8e30ed37cbe0de6) and there rotation isnt rotating towards the player EDIT: i found the problem with the lag I changed `            self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( self.shootsright, -angle, 0 )` instead of 1 I put 0 now the sprites wont show norr rotate AHHHHHHH

Comment: have you considered doing `self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, -angle)`? `rotozoom` is used for rotating and scaling at the same time, while `rotate` is just for rotation, and it does not affect the scale of the image

Comment: @HabibIsmail The third arg of `rotozoom()` is the multiplying floating point scale factor. Setting it to 0 means you want it to scale it to 0 size, Not likely what you want. As CiroGarcía already said, since you do not really seem to want to scale it you should use the simpler `rotate()`.